# Two forms on the same page needs the value of the same element

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two forms on a php page. They post to different pages when they are submitted. Both forms need the value of a dropbox that is inside form A. How do I get this value posted when form B is submitted?

Answer (score 1):

Create a hidden input in form B and put a change event on the dropdown in form A which copies it's value to that.

Example (using jQuery - if you want to do it with another library or plain javascript you'll need to adapt it).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#copy-src').change(function(){
        $('#copy-target').val( $(this).val() );
    }).change();
});
</script>

<form id="a" action="/a">
    <input type="text" name="a_only" />
    <select id="copy-src" name="also_b">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="foo">Foo</option>
        <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<form id="b" action="/b">
    <input type="text" name="b_only" />
    <input type="hidden" name="also_a" id="copy-target" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The `.change(function(){})` creates a change event to copy the value while the final `.change()` triggers that event (on page load) to ensure the value is right initially.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Question is not tagged as jQuery

Comment: Why is it not an answer?  It is describing how to solve the problem.  Have now added an example, but still, as a description of a solution it was an answer.

Comment: I can give an answer in PHP also, or in another language. In SO, it is important to provide a solution according to tags of question. That is why I have answered question in Pure Javascript. Anyway, thanks for your effort

Comment: @Hüseyin BABAL I donät think you can give an answer in PHP to copying values from one form to another before the form is submitted (i.e. within the browser).  At least I'd like to see it!  jQuery is not another langauge, it's an extra library of functions to make javascript a bit easier and I qualified it's use in the question.  I would actually suggest that someone new to web programming should verys eriously consider using a helper library on top of javascript and I personally find jQuery to easiest (and probably the most widely supported).  But your answer in pure js is good too.

Comment: A great THANK YOU! for the answers. I had fought with this for hours. It is also good to be reminded that I have to study jQuery sooner than later.

Comment: Testing showed that:
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = "dropdownValue";
    formB.appendChild(input);
did not work. Even when I added input.value = value.
I changed it to:
document.formB.week.value = value;
with:
<input type="hidden" name="week" />
in formB itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy dropbox value to Form B while submitting;

On formB;

```
<form onsubmit="getDropdownValue()">
.....
</form>
```

And in function;

```
function getDropdownValue() {
    var formB = document.getElementById("formB");

    // Get selected value from FormA
    var e = document.getElementById("formADropdown");
    var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    // Append it to formB
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = "dropdownValue";
    formB.appendChild(input);   
}
```

You can see demo: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3xTnK/)** . I demo when you click submit, you will see dropdownvalue from form A will be copied to formB before submit